# How can I generate a generalized product to two lists in a special way?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language, pure-function

Let's say I have two lists, and I'd like to generate a "cartesian product" from these two. Specifically

Inputs:

```
A = {{{1}}, {{2}}, {{1}, {2}}};
B = {8, 9};
```

Desired output:

```
X = {{{{1}} -> 8, {{1}} -> 9}, {{{2}} -> 8, {{2}} -> 9}, {{{1}, {2}} -> 
   8, {{1}, {2}} -> 9}}
```

I tried

```
f[#1, #2]& /@ {A, B}
```

but it didn't work. I also tried to use `Thread`, but that  didn't work either.

#### Edit

`Outer` doesn't really work either, since it goes to all the leaves and extracts them first.

```
Outer[#1 -> #2, A, B]
```

> {{{{1 -> 8, 1 -> 9}}}, {{{2 -> 8, 2 -> 9}}}, {{{1 -> 8, 1 -> 9}}, {{2 -> 8, 2 -> 9}}}}

Comment: Have you seen the 3rd argument of `Outer`? `Outer[Rule, A, B, 1]`

Comment: @rm-rf I have now!

Comment: and outer is much faster than my Table suggestion.

Comment: People, surely this question is a duplicate.  Please exert the effort to look for duplicates before answering; thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the linked post with the only difference being that `Rule` is the function instead of `Join`. There are several answers there, most/all of which should be applicable here (cc @Mr.Wizard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to apply the third argument of `Outer` as rm -rf suggested. With your `A` and `B`,

```
Outer[#1 -> #2 &, A, B, 1]
```

gives

```
{{{{1}} -> 8, {{1}} -> 9}, {{{2}} -> 8, {{2}} -> 9}, {{{1}, {2}} ->  8, {{1}, {2}} -> 9}}
```

as you requested. To check (with your `X`)

```
Outer[#1 -> #2 &, A, B, 1] == X

True
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be misinterpreting, but is this what you are looking for ?

```
Outer[f, {a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}]

(* {{f[a, 1], f[a, 2], f[a, 3]}, {f[b, 1], f[b, 2], 
  f[b, 3]}, {f[c, 1], f[c, 2], f[c, 3]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
A = {{{1}}, {{2}}, {{1}, {2}}};
B = {8, 9};
Table[{i -> j}, {i, A}, {j, B}]
```

which gives me:

```
{{{{{1}} -> 8}, {{{1}} -> 9}}, {{{{2}} -> 8}, {{{2}} -> 
    9}}, {{{{1}, {2}} -> 8}, {{{1}, {2}} -> 9}}}
```

I've got one too many sets of braces, it looks like.

Comment: Changing `{i->j}` to `First@{i->j}` gives the desired output I think.